# SQL Server : get the lowest value

Tags: sql-server, min

Goal : I want to find the lowest NR of `DayInStock` where the `Cummsold > Balance`

The query is as follow

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
       a.MonthNR
     , a.DayNR
     , a.DayInStock
     , a.CummSold
     , a.WarehouseID
     , a.ItemID
     , a.[Group]
     , a.Balance
     , a.CountryNumber
     , a.Country
  FROM dbo.VW_Critical_01_01 AS a 
  JOIN (SELECT MIN(DayInStock) AS DayInStock
             , MIN(CummSold) AS Cummsold
             , Balance
             , ItemID
             , [Group]
          FROM dbo.VW_Critical_01_01
         WHERE CummSold > Balance
         GROUP BY DayInStock, CummSold, Balance, ItemID, [Group]
      ) AS b 
   ON b.DayInStock = a.DayInStock 
  AND b.ItemID = a.ItemID 
  AND b.[Group] = a.[Group]
ORDER BY a.ItemID, a.DayInStock
```

The query gives my as result:

```
MonthNR DayNR DayInStock CummSold   ItemID   Group  Balance CountryNumber   Country
**2 4   11  2902.492233 100049V3            1   2894    370 Sweden
2   4   11  2902.492233 100049V3            1   2894    280 Norway
2   4   11  2902.492233 100049V3            1   2894    270 Portugal
2   4   11  2902.492233 100049V3            1   2894    460 Finland
2   4   11  2902.492233 100049V3            1   2894    110 Switzerland**

2   5   12  2982.376102 100049V3            1   2894    370 Sweden
2   5   12  2982.376102 100049V3            1   2894    280 Norway
2   5   12  2982.376102 100049V3            1   2894    270 Portugal
2   5   12  2982.376102 100049V3            1   2894    460 Finland
2   5   12  2982.376102 100049V3            1   2894    110 Switzerland
```

Where I only want to see the values marked as **BOLD**

As for those the `CummSold > Balance` (2902 is larger then 2894) and the `daynumber` is the lowest 11 instead of 12

My SQL Server knowledge seems to stop here. I searched and tried numerous things and perhaps i'm just overlooking something very "stupid"

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2005+ you can try using analytical functions:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  a.MonthNR,
            a.DayNR,
            a.DayInStock,
            a.CummSold,
            a.WarehouseID,
            a.ItemID,
            a.[Group],
            a.Balance,
            a.CountryNumber,
            a.Country,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID, [Group], Country
                              ORDER BY DayInStock) RN
    FROM dbo.VW_Critical_01_01 a
    WHERE CummSold > Balance
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Tried that...<br>
Funny unlogic results..<br>
2 1 **8** 5230.86034731307 100100D5    1 5229 270 Portugal<br>
2 2 **9** 5388.53535357758 100100D5    1 5229 80 France<br>
2 3 **10** 5546.21035984209 100100D5    1 5229 270 Portugal<br>
2 4 **11** 5703.8853661066  100100D5    1 5229 110 Switzerland<br> 
2 5 **12** 5861.56037237111 100100D5    1 5229 470 Denmark<br>
<br>
Where i would need the same day's and now the increment.

Comment: @Marty210578 Then I don't really know what you expect as a result. Can you clarify your criteria?, do you want those results for an `Item`?, try changing that on the `PARTITION BY` clause.

Comment: First : thanks for the input
For some reason the question doesn't contain the BOLD selection.
The query i constructed gives as a result the whole list with 5 times dayinstock "11" and 5 times dayinstock "12". The objective is to have the lowest DAYINSTOCK for the itemID+Group+Country  
For this example i would need 5 lines with DayInStock 11 

Hope this makes a bit sense for you.

Comment: @Marty210578 Ok, the part where you say that is the lowest `DayInStock` for the combination of `itemID+Group+Country` actually helps a lot. I updated my answer, try now and let me know if it helps you

Comment: no.. after the change i see at least the DAYInStock in a sorted orders.. Only i see again 11 and 12. Funny thing is.. the RN is always 1

Comment: @Marty210578 Ok, and are you sure that for that combination of Item, Group and Country the lowest `DayInStock` is 11 instead of 12?, maybe the results are correct

Comment: I need to deep into that perhaps.. Will be monday. Highly appreciated your time and effort. Have a great weekend

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
select DayNR
     , DayInStock
     , CummSold
     , WarehouseID
     , ItemID
     , [Group]
     , Balance
     , CountryNumber
     , Country
from(SELECT DayInStock 
          , DayNR
          , DayInStock
          , CummSold
          , WarehouseID
          , ItemID
          , [Group]
          , Balance
          , CountryNumber
          , Country
          , min(DayInStock) over (partition by itemID,Group,Country) as minDayInStock
      FROM dbo.VW_Critical_01_01
      WHERE CummSold > Balance
)V
where V.DayInStock = V.minDayInStock
```